# Why does my dropout function in Theano slow down convolution greatly?

Tags: cuda, neural-network, theano, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am learning Theano. I wrote a simple dropout function as below:

```
import theano.tensor as T
srng = T.shared_randomstreams.RandomStreams()

def drop(input, dropout=0.0):
    if T.gt(dropout, 0.):
        retain_prob = 1 - dropout.astype('floatX')
        mask = srng.binomial(n=1, p=retain_prob, size=input.shape, dtype='floatX')
        return input * mask / retain_prob
    else:
        return input
```

When I apply this function to the input of the first two convolutional layers, the average time spent on each image increases from 0.5ms to about 2.5ms! Does anyone know what could be the reason for such drastic slow down?

I am using a GTX 980 card with cuDNN installed.

Answer (score 8):

RandomStream only works on the CPU. Therefore `mask` has to be copied from CPU to GPU every time drop is called, which is the reason for the drastic slow down. To avoid this, I now use [random stream implementation which works on GPU](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html#other-implementations).

Comment: However, even the MRG version would cause drastic slow down

Comment: Just tested it, and MRG version didn't cause any slowdown at all when applied to fully connected layers (Maxwell Titan X, CUDA 7.5, Theano 0.9.0dev4).          
For comparison, T.shared_randomstreams.RandomStreams() version was causing a slowdown factor of 10!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a similar problem as mine ([Lasagne dropoutlayer does not utilize GPU efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33592778/lasagne-dropoutlayer-does-not-utilize-gpu-efficiently)). 
Have you checked that you code sets `cuda_enabled = True` somewhere? otherwise you can manually set it in line 93 of [https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/sandbox/cuda/**init**.py](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/sandbox/cuda/__init__.py).
I know this is not a elegant solution but it solved my problem for now. :)